# What is the maximum theoretical height upto which our oceans can rise?

Tags: water, earth

The question is framed from a physics point of view so we will assume water is an indefinite resource. All I am interested in is if we go on adding water into our oceans then what is the maximum height the oceans will rise before water starts turning into ice and escaping into space.

How will rotation of the earth affect a huge body of water surrounding earth? Say for example, planet Miller (the first planet) explored in Interstellar.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on what-if.xkcd.com

Comment: It is possible I must have read it somewhere in xkcd because I have read the book what if. Please tell me which question it was or a link to it (I couldn't find it within the website) and I really want to know the answer from a physics point of view although it is not of much consequence. Any help is greatly appreciated.